# dynamic content table alignment properly

Tags: html, css

Please refer below code

```
<table align="center" class="section">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Ram</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Reason </td>
        <td>  xxx </td>
        <td> yyyy </td>
        <td>.....</td>
        .....................
    </tr>
</table>
```

fiddle link :  http://jsfiddle.net/WKgu4/

**Current output :**

```
Name     Ram
Age      20
Reason   xxx     yyyy
```

Reason tr will have "n" number of td,that means dynamic content will be added  as required 
so if any td added in reason tr i want output like below

**Expected Output:**

```
Name     Ram
Age      20
Reason   xxx
         yyyy
         zzzz
         ccccc
         vvvvvv
```

how to align the reason tr ? because it has dynamic content.  "n" number of reasons added dynamically. but i want to align like above table

**Css :**

```
.section tr td
{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

need to align the dynamic content of reason in one by one.

how to resolve this ?

Comment: you could put all rows in single `<td>` and use `<br/>` to have multiple lines. Then use `vertical-align: top` for your cells

Comment: As mentioned above - you could use a single `<td>` http://jsfiddle.net/WKgu4/1/ I've used an unordered list for the reasons.

Comment: Browser will consider maximum number of `<td>` in a `<tr>` to the table column count. So please dont expect better than this

Comment: Use CSS3, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251887/dynamic-content-table-alignment-properly/22252101#answer-22252101)

Comment: Offtopic, your first tablerow has no closing tag (`</tr>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to change HTML try below **CSS**:

```
.section tr:last-child{
    vertical-align:top;
}
.section tr td
{
    padding: 10px;
}
.section tr:last-child>td~td{
    display:table-row;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChMp4/)

Comment: style all td's after first td within that tr

Answer (score 1):

you need to repeat `<tr>` for having above output.

what you can do is

```
<table align="center" class="section">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Ram</td>
      <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td> Reason </td>
          <td>  xxx </td>
      </tr>
<!- repeating part-->
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> yyy</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> zzz</td>
      </tr>
------
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you put all reasons in 2nd TD break apart with BR tag like

```
<tr>
  <td> Reason </td>
  <td> xxx
       <br />yyyy
       ...
  </td>
</tr>
```

and add in CSS

```
.section tr td
{
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirly sure why you'd want to do this, but you can do it with CSS3:

```
tr:nth-child(3) td:not(:nth-child(1)) {display:table-row;}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) {vertical-align:top;}
```

Check out the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fwnHG/

Also, this fiddle uses `<th>` so it's a bit more semantically correct - http://jsfiddle.net/ZB2Gn/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table align="center" class="section">
  <tr>
<td>  Name
</td>
<td>
Ram
</td>
      <tr>
          <td>
              Age
          </td>
          <td>
              20
          </td>
      </tr>
         <td> Reason </td>
         <td>  xxx </td>
      <tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td><td> yyyy </td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

?